# <s:a> attribute disabled not working

Tags: jquery, html, struts2

i use struts2  like:

```
<s:a id="beforePage" disabled="true">beforePage</s:a>
```

but disabled doesn't work,it is the same as without disabled attirbute.

To my surprise,when i use jquery,like:

```
<s:a id="beforePage">beforePage</s:a> 
$("#beforePage").attr("disabled","true");
```

the disabled attribute work! so,i'm confused on it..
please give me an explanation for that,thanks a lot.

Comment: Links cannot be disabled like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 `<s:a>` tag finally generates html `<a> tag. There is no "disabled" attribute defined in``tag (i.e.`` does not support disabled attribute). Hence it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The disabled attribute in the more recent versions of HTML is simply to exist in the element, like such, or as the attribute's value as well:

```
<s:a id="beforePage" disabled="disabled">beforePage</s:a>
```

Comment: thanks,but it Encountered error:equal symbol expected whehn i try your code